# Displaying distance on an elevation graph when rendering directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to display an elevation graph within my application that also shows the distance from the start of a particular routes.

I found this example which shows a basic elevation graph for a route.

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_elevation-profile_distance.html

Is there a way to accurately display the distance along the x axis in the graph at the bottom?

The fact that the google.maps.ElevationResult doesn't include a distance seems to make this very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example with driving directions and mileage in each county:

http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_directions.html

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry but that's the same as the example that I provided. They both do not show the distance on the horizontal axis of the elevation graph.

Answer (score 0):

The elevation service results contains the latitude/longitude coordinates, elevation and resolution of the result.  From the coordinates you can compute the distance between the points (using the [geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) computeDistanceBetween method).

Comment: I did think of this but it seems excessive. If I have an ElevationResult that contains hundreds of latLng coordinates I was hoping that I didn't have to make a separate call for each one to calculate the distance between them.

Comment: I think the elevations service probably spaces the points out evenly, so you may be able to get your result by only calculating one distance (or a few).